# What is the Visual Studio behavior when using GIT per project?

Tags: c#, git, visual-studio, tfs, tfvc

After reading about using GIT with Visual Studio solution, I understand that it is preferable to use GIT per project, at least for project which represent a (re-usable) common library. If you have a solution with many projects specific to that solution, using only one repository could be acceptable. For common library, it appears logical to me to have one repository for it in order to be able to fix bugs in the common library from where you detect it and have only one history for all changes.

Using one GIT per common project means that you have more than one GIT repository for any solution that produce an executable that use one or more common library.

According to this: [Visual Studio suggestion - Allow multiple Git repositories to be active at once](https://visualstudio.uservoice.com/forums/121579-visual-studio-ide/suggestions/8960629-allow-multiple-git-repositories-to-be-active-at-on), Visual Studio seems to not support many GIT repository seamlessly. (1995 request)

Does Visual Studio 2017 implement the previous suggestion and manage many GIT repository per solution? (ex: one per project for some projects and one per solution for the solution itself and all other specific projects to this solution)? In other words, does Microsoft will see and manage changes per project/GIT or do I have to works with only one GIT at the solution Level?

Just as a side one (this is not the primary question - the real question is in the previous paragraph): If Visual Studio does not allow multiple GIT repo to be active at once, wouldn't be better to stick with TFS for the moment for any development with common library?

Comment: How is sticking with TFS better than GIT?  Are you running many TFS instances?

Comment: Really [GIT Submodules](http://octonator.com/git-submodule-explained/) should be used for this type of development. Depends on the GIT extension you are using how much it is supported in the UI. As far as I know, [this works fine with GitHub](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/devops/2017/12/08/new-git-features-in-vs2017-update-5/), I'm not sure about GitLab.

Comment: @P.Brian.Mackey, TFS is server base (global). That mean that you can use one instance for any projects. Only one history per project.

Comment: There is a [User Voice Poll](https://visualstudio.uservoice.com/forums/121579-visual-studio-ide/suggestions/8960629-allow-multiple-git-repositories-to-be-active-at-on) to allow multiple repo support in VS, I would recommend voting.

Comment: @RonBeyer, I'm really not an expert of GIT. I red that using Submodules is the way to go. Doing so would works fine with Visual Studio - one solution and few projects - specific to solution and common libs)??? Submodule is a GIT repo linked to a parent? User voice is the same Link I refer to!

Comment: Consider tagging this question with tfs.  I think @RonBeyer is correct regarding submodules.  However, I don't think this question can be answered without also considering how TFS works.  I have used both, but it's been a very long time since I used TFS so I don't think I can make a solid comparison today.  I'm also having trouble understanding precisely what is being asked as there is a communication barrier.

Comment: @P.Brian.Mackey, I added TFS tag. But in fact I would like to use GIT without TFS if ever possible. I have one project that I did so with GitHub. But GIT is setup at the solution level on that solution (only one GIT at solution). Yes submodules seams to be the way to go. But, if you read the User Voice Poll about GIT, you can see that Visual Studio does not manage well more than one GIT (at least that is my understanding), that is what I want to clarify. I don't understand what you don't understand. Did you read the suggestion (User Voice Poll)? I tried to clarify my question.

Comment: Let's be clear about something: TFS is an application. **TFVC** is a source control platform that is supported within TFS. Git is also a source control platform that is supported within TFS. When you say "TFS", are you talking about TFVC?

Comment: @DanielMann, Good question, I don't know Visual Studio Internals. I'm actually using TFS as source control. I want to switch to GIT only without TFS like GitLab or BitBucket if it is possible (it should because I'm using GitHub for few projects). In fact I would like to not use TFS at all, if ever possible. I'm currently using Visual Studio with TFS but I have no clear idea how it connects to TFS. I don't think it is important in the current context. I think that removing everything related to TFS in Vicusl Studio would not prevent me using an extrenal GIT source control.

Comment: When using a Git Repo for a re-usable project, does it make sense to keep it part of the solution? It would become its own solution and the reference would then change from a project reference to a nuget package or some other kind of package management solution. Having a solution open with multiple projects from different repositories is a problem waiting to happen.

Comment: @jessehouwing, If I understand you properly, you recommend to manage re-usable project on their own solution (ex with their own tests) and only include binaries of that re-usable project in a specific solution. I partly agree. In fact, my experience tell me it is probably the best in perfect world but in concrete day to day, I personally do too much mistakes when developing re-usable library and have to maintain them too much often to separate them from a specific development. Having it apart would makes me code in specific solution instead of proper place (due probably to my random laziness).

Comment: @jessehouwing, Also, usually, all the requirement environment (or context) required to test a re-usable functionality is already exactly happen in course of developing specific solution which could save lots of developing time. I understand that next time I will add something, all the tests required to validate previous functionality could be lost if doing like I do actually because no tests at all are coded (only validate in a specific context). My own experience tell me that code does not live longer enough these days... when put in balance, it is more beneficial to test directly in usage.

Comment: In that case, don't go through all the hassle and maintain the code in context. If you ever want to really make it reusable, extract it to a separate repo.

Comment: @jessehouwing, I'm not sure to follow you. If I have the solution to a git and a project to another git. If I want to check in, does it will validate changes against the 2 different git and do check in into the 2 git?

Comment: So my answer is: why. What value does this bring you. At the moment it's adding frustration. You can always extract it so put everything in one repo. Heck. The whole windows sources is in a is glerups git repo.

Comment: @jessehouwing, What I understand from your comment is: if I prefer to manage only one repo per re-usable project, I should stick with TFS because Microsoft does not support many git repo per solution in Visual Studio 2017.

Comment: That's absolutely bit what I'm saying. But you'd need to use submodules or subtree and manage those partially through the commandline. Reusable components should be built in such a way that they don't change regularly and that way you can focus most effort on the main solution. Vs 2017 has some support for these concepts. Or you can use a monorepo, which is a fine alternative. Or you can go the nuget route. You have options.

Comment: @jessehouwing, I think you answered the question. As far as I understand, it is not yet supported by Visual Studio 2017. There is some alternatives like managing submodules manually or by design choice through managing re-usable project in isolation. Do you think you can just transform your previous comment into an answer? I will set it as accepted and close this question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

While there has not been great support for multi repo solutions in the past, this is about to change. In Visual Studio 16.11 Preview 1, there is now a much more fully featured Git client, multiple repositories are detected and users can easily switch between them using a repository selector in the status bar.

See this blog for further information: [Enhanced Productivity with Git in Visual Studio](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/visualstudio/enhanced-productivity-with-git-in-visual-studio/)

Answer (score 3):

This is a controversial topic. You have a few options:

- **Mono-repo**. All your code lives in a single repository, whether they're split up into separate solutions or not is up to you. If your dependencies are "possibly reusable" then this is the simplest starting point. If you ever really start to reuse your components, you can always break them out.
- **Separate repositories + Package Manager (npm, Nuget)**. Put each reusable project in a separate solution, optionally in a separate repository. Have a CI build automatically create a package and publish it to the VSTS package management feed.
- **SubModules**: Create a master repository with your solution, create a separate repository for each reusable component with just the `csproj` and the sources for that component. Visual Studio 2017 has rudimentary support for submodules. But with a separate git client on the side (Tower, SourceTree) or simply with some commandline mastery, you can make this work just fine.
- **Subtree**: Create a master repository with your solution, create a separate repository for each reusable component with just the `csproj` and the sources for that component. [Visual Studio 2017 has no support for subtrees at the moment](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/idea/576356/somewhat-simpler-than-git-submodules-would-like-vs.html). But with a separate git client on the side (Tower, SourceTree) or simply with some commandline mastery, you can make this work just fine.
- **Multi-repo**: Create separate repositories for each project, put a solution alongside it. Manage each sub-component separately and there is no concept of a submodule tracking. Visual Studio will actively fight you in this setup, as it will only support a single master repository at a time

In the end it is your choice. Each solution has its own benefits and there are examples of each out there. The Windows sources are all stored in a single monstrous mono-repo with all its reusable components in the same repository. It has great advantages with regards to knowing which files and which versions work together and which won't. But the repository is so big that Microsoft built GVFS in order to allow their developers to work on a 300GB working directory.

If your components are currently not being re-used and if your tests are more integration tests than real unit tests, then it makes sense to join them up into the same repository.

You can always decide to fix this when the need arises. You can always try to keep these projects as separate as possible. The .NET route will most logically lead you to Nuget though... Also because it handles the versioning aspects and the ease of sharing between projects without having to build the sources everywhere.